# load object with uvw unwrap into three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, fbx, uvw

I've got a 3D object with an unwrapped uvw map, done in 3ds max, and saved as an .fbx.  When I load the object into a 3js scene and apply a texture, the mapping is lost.  How do I keep the uvw mapping on the object?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be more related to 3DS Max.

Have you applied the UVW modifier ?

Are your Uv on the good channel ? (Threejs use first uv channel for Map, bump, roughness, metalness, etc. And second channel for lightmap and Ao)

When you import your FBX model into 3DSMax or Blender, have you checked the model exported still have UVs ?